# In OpenGL, (how) can I depth test between two depth buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

Say I have two depth buffers ("DA" and "DB"). I'd like to attach DA to a framebuffer, and render to it in the normal/"traditional" way (every fragment depth tests against GL_LESS, if it passes, it is drawn and it's depth is written to the depth buffer).

Then, I'd like to attach DB- here I'd want to reference/use DB in the traditional way, but also depth test against DA with GL_GREATER. If the fragment passes both tests, I'd still just like to write depth to DB.

What this would accomplish is anything drawn in the second pass would only draw if it is *behind* the contents of the first pass, but *in front* of any other contents in the second pass.

**Does OpenGL 2.1 (or OpenGL ES 2) offer any of this functionality? What could I do to work around it not formally offering it?**

If it doesn't offer it, here's an idea for how I'd do it, that I would like to be sanity checked...

You attach a render buffer that acts as a depth buffer, then manually populate it with depths. And manually perform the "if depth greater than texel at DA" test (when failing, discard the fragment). I'm curious what problems I'd run into? Is there an easy way to emulate the depth precision of formally specified depth buffers? Would the performance be awful? Any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to have multiple depth buffers. I thought there might at least be vendor specific extensions, but a search through the extension registry came up empty even for that.

What you already started considering in the last paragraph looks like the only reasonably straightforward option that comes to mind. You use a depth texture as your second depth buffer, and discard fragments based on their comparison with the value from the depth texture in your fragment shader.

You don't have to manually populate the depth texture. If the depth values are generated as the result of an earlier rendering pass, you can copy them from the primary depth buffer to a depth texture using `glCopyTexImage2D()`. This function is available in OpenGL 2.1. In newer versions, you can also use `glBlitFramebuffer()` to perform the copy.

On your concerns:

- Precision is a very valid concern. I had some fairly severe precision issues when I played with something similar in the past. They can probably be solved, but you definitely need to watch out for it, and carefully think about what your precision requirements are, and how you can fudge the values if necessary.
- I would certainly expect performance to suffer somewhat. The fixed function depth buffer has the advantage of heavy optimizations, like early depth testing, that you won't get with your "home made" depth buffer. I wouldn't necessarily expect it to be horrible, though. And if this is what you need, it's worth trying.

I think this is pretty much a no go in ES 2.0, at least without relying on extensions. You could potentially consider writing depth values into color textures, but I think it would get very ugly and inefficient. ES 2.0 is great for its simplicity. But for what you're planning to do, you're exceeding its intended feature set. ES 3.0 adds depth textures, and some other features that could come into play.

Comment: Ok. Was afraid of that. Luckily, my use case allows me to fudge "DA" as just world_pos.z < 0.0, with *minimal* artifacts, which is acceptable. (I'll accept your answer- but leaving it open for a bit longer to give anyone a chance to produce some brilliant hack that gives me performance-unaltering perfect double-depth testing).